# DbContext object dont see its properties - DbSets

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My Web API C# application has Entity Framework built in Code First Way.
I have a DbContext class like below:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext() 
        : base("name=AppDbContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }

    public static AppDbContext Create()
    {   
        return new AppDbContext();
    }

}
```

In a Controller I call DbContext as a variable.

```
public class AppController : ApiController
{
    private DbContext _context;

    public AppController()
    {
        _context = new AppDbContext();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Authorize(User user)
    {
        User currentUser = _context.Users......
```

In last line from controller variable _context can't recognized it's property. 
[image: No DbSets in list of properties]

What to do to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change type of field from base `DbContext` to `AppDbContext`

```
private AppDbContext _context;
```

DbSet properties are declared in child class thus they cannot be visible through reference of base class type.

Comment: Thanks, Its working! What a stupid mistake I did!